# Getting img src from xslt value from child element in xml

Tags: html, xml, image, xslt

I would like to retrieve the img source from XML using XSLT, however the element for image source is in children element, this has caused me for having trouble to retrieve the value. I tried with Attribute Template, however it still can't seem to work

```
//  XML
<recipeImgPath>
    <imgPath>images/upload/thumbnail_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-recipeThumb.png</imgPath>
    <imgPath>images/upload/slider_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-slider.png</imgPath>
    <imgPath>images/upload/featured_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-featuredRecipe.png</imgPath>
    <imgPath>images/upload/background_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-recipeBackground.png</imgPath>
</recipeImgPath>
```

and

```
//    part of my XSLT code which need to get the source of image
<a href="recipe-page-1.php">
<img src="{imgPath}" alt=""/>
<div class="hover-cover"></div>
<div class="hover-icon">View Recipe</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT? In particular, who node are you currently positioned on when you create the `img` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see your xslt but you can try following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="imgPath">
        <a href="recipe-page-1.php">
            <img src="{.}" alt=""/>
            <div class="hover-cover"/>
            <div class="hover-icon">View Recipe</div>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Which produce following output:

```
<output>
    <recipeImgPath>
        <a href="recipe-page-1.php">
            <img src="images/upload/thumbnail_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-recipeThumb.png" alt=""/>
            <div class="hover-cover"/>
            <div class="hover-icon">View Recipe</div>
        </a>
        <a href="recipe-page-1.php">
            <img src="images/upload/slider_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-slider.png" alt=""/>
            <div class="hover-cover"/>
            <div class="hover-icon">View Recipe</div>
        </a>
        <a href="recipe-page-1.php">
            <img src="images/upload/featured_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-featuredRecipe.png" alt=""/>
            <div class="hover-cover"/>
            <div class="hover-icon">View Recipe</div>
        </a>
        <a href="recipe-page-1.php">
            <img src="images/upload/background_1488881669_mango-avocado-salsa-recipeBackground.png" alt=""/>
            <div class="hover-cover"/>
            <div class="hover-icon">View Recipe</div>
        </a>
    </recipeImgPath>
</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach for simply putting the `imgPath` element's text into the appropriate `href` attributes would be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="recipeImgPath/imgPath">
   <a href="recipe-page-1.php">
     <img src="{text()}" alt=""/>
     <div class="hover-cover"></div>
     <div class="hover-icon">View Recipe</div>
   </a> 
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Add an *identity template* as desired (or as in the other answer) to replicate the other elements.